# How to get a file from a network windows directory and move to my Python Django project directory?

Tags: python, django, windows, macos

I'm programming in a MacOS and using Python + Django. I must to get some files in our private network (Windows network) and move them to our server. There, Python/Django will read these files and save the data in a database. How can I do that?

**What I have tried**

```
source_path = "smb://server-name/GRUPOS/TECNOLOGIA_INFORMACAO/Dashboard Diretoria/"
dest_path = "./static/reports/". # This is my static folder where I want to move the file
file_name = "general_reports.csv"
shutil.copyfile(source_path + file_name, dest_path + file_name)
```

It gives the follow error:

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'smb://server-name/GRUPOS/TECNOLOGIA_INFORMACAO/Dashboard
>   Diretoria/general_reports.csv'

This path (source_path) I just copied and past from the Finder, so... I think that it's correct. I have already searched at StackOverflow and I have tried other methods like put "r" before the path... Nothing....

**Technologies used**

- Python 3.6;
- Django 3.0.5;
- Mac OSX;
- Windows Network.

Thank you for your help and patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import an SMB client libary for python or you mount that drive before you work there

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try it and I come back son.

Comment: I tried to import this library https://pypi.org/project/PySmbClient/ and open the file. It shows this error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'smbclient': b'smbclient'. Have you any idea about it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thank you @Van de Wack.

This is the complete solution:

1. Install the pysmb library (https://pypi.org/project/pysmb/):

   pip install pysmb
2. Import the library to your code:

   from smb.SMBConnection import SMBConnection
3. The follow code is a example to list all directories:

   ```
   server_ip = "10.110.10.10" # Take your server IP - I have put a fake IP :)
   server_name = 'myserver' # The servername for the IP above
   share_name = "GRUPOS" # This is the principal folder of your network that you want's to connect
   network_username = 'myuser' # This is your network username
   network_password = '***' # This is your network password
   machine_name = 'myuser@mac-mc70006405' # Your machine name
   conn = SMBConnection(network_username, network_password, machine_name, server_name, use_ntlm_v2 = True)
   assert conn.connect(server_ip, 139)
   files = conn.listPath(share_name, "/TECNOLOGIA_INFORMACAO/Dashboard Diretoria/")
   for item in files:
      print(item.filename)
   ```